# PostgreSQL - Set permanent timezone

Tags: postgresql

How can i set the default timezone in postgresql?

I tried updating the postgresql.conf file in /etc/postgresql/13/main/ directory and then did a sudo service postgresql restart

But the timezone in db shows 'Asia/Kolkata'

I expected it to be 'UTC'

Can anyone tell me if anything is missing here.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is your session time zone?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name session time zone is 'Asia/Kolkata'

Comment: Then you need to change that as well in your client using `set timezone='UTC'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my node application is set to UTC. When i login to db and run show timezone; it shows 'Asia/Kolkata'

Comment: Impossible to say what you did wrong, since you only describe what you did in words, rather than showing your commands. You could have edited the wrong file. You could have forgotten to remove a comment in front of the line. Run `SELECT ' FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'timezone';` and add the output to your question. Edit the question for that, and use formatted text, not an image.